# Agrandar div segun contenido con css

Tags: css, html5, div

Resulta que tengo un una seccion en donde estoy poniendo una especie de galeria de imagenes. El contenedor padre de todo tiene una altura de 600px, y adentro tiene otros dos contenedores que contienen las imagenes, el problema es que a medida que aumento las imagenes, obviamente el contenedor de las imagenes cambia de alto.

Como podría hacer para que el contenedor padre, osea el section, se agrande automaticamente depende del contenido?

Gracias

```css
  /* PORTFOLIO */

    .portfolio{

 height: 500px;
 background:#f2f2f2;
 padding:20px;
 

    }

    .portfolioTitulo{

 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 35px;

    }

    .trabajo{

 width: 30%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-right:3px;

    }

    .thumb{

 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

    }

    .thumb img {

 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: top;
 border-radius: 3px;

    }


    .contenedorPortfolio2{

 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:center;
 
    }
```

```html
    <section class="portfolio">

      <div class="contenedorPortfolio">
       
       <h1 class="portfolioTitulo">Portfolio</h1>

       <div class="contenedorPortfolio2">

        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
         
        </div>
        
        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
         
        </div>

        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
         
        </div>

        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
         
        </div>

        <div class="trabajo">
           
         <div class="thumb">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
         </div>
         
        </div>

       </div>
      
      </div>

     </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{background: #ff015b; height: auto; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
<div>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
</div>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an everti salutandi eum, altera facilisis quo ad. Ad has eros facilis. Has graeci interesset no. Zril petentium ea vim, at sea saepe ignota intellegebat. Ad eum denique urbanitas pertinacia, est quis esse essent et, solum repudiare cu vel.

An facer iusto signiferumque nec. Est eligendi inciderint definitionem et. Ea ius melius vocent utamur, no legere nostro torquatos mea, nullam voluptatibus pri id. Ea mei assum vocent commune, nisl munere minimum ius ut.

Vis an libris iuvaret alienum, duo ne ceteros maiorum. Mei ex doming euismod 
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an everti salutandi eum, altera facilisis quo ad. Ad has eros facilis. Has graeci interesset no. Zril petentium ea vim, at sea saepe ignota intellegebat. Ad eum denique urbanitas pertinacia, est quis esse essent et, solum repudiare cu vel.

An facer iusto signiferumque nec. Est eligendi inciderint definitionem et. Ea ius melius vocent utamur, no legere nostro torquatos mea, nullam voluptatibus pri id. Ea mei assum vocent commune, nisl munere minimum ius ut.

Vis an libris iuvaret alienum, duo ne ceteros maiorum. Mei ex doming euismod definitionem. Vis vide laudem ubique eu, euismod constituto cu qui. Ut qui minim aliquip, ea alii indoctum scribentur sed, mea no sonet torquatos. Mea et eirmod accusata antiopam. Et tantas dolore pri, ei numquam prodesset eos, iuvaret facilis ponderum at per. Copiosae oportere an vix, mel etiam dicam te.

Est nibh nihil graece no, per et falli doming erroribus, novum debitis explicari no his. Errem apeirian ex cum. Has ex eruditi disputando, vim utroque veritus vituperata ut. Vidit disputando mel at.

Duo an euismod delenit. Odio cibo probatus ut nam, ut sit autem iuvaret expetendis. Sea ne tota nobis mandamus, ius in legimus patrioque. Cum no dolor decore facete, mea id dicta intellegat interesset, cibo mazim noluisse ex vim. Eius definiebas ullamcorper et eum. Et cum solum exerci delenit, quo primis vivendo et, mel ei impedit adolescens. An est clita postulant, mei volutpat hendrerit ut.

Vel ex iuvaret adversarium conclusionemque. Pri diceret tibique dissentiet ei, et per modo fastidii, no sale ocurreret temporibus quo. Option explicari scripserit quo in, vix an liber debitis sadipscing, suas ornatus vituperatoribus has ne. Quis equidem ad his, assum timeam argumentum nam eu.

Cum ne omnium tibique. Dicunt voluptaria mel at. Cum at magna elitr, debitis accusamus similique nam te. Eu mea apeirian voluptatibus, mei id harum dicit philosophia. Altera quidam his et, has at eruditi nusquam. Ad iuvaret docendi adversarium mel, at eum blandit adipiscing philosophia.

Eos mucius scaevola id, eripuit vulputate ea cum. Qui no quot adipiscing incorrupte. Usu id mucius fabellas reprehendunt. Ullum inermis liberavisse eos at.

Mel ad quidam timeam, integre maiorum elaboraret mei ut. Mel eu omnes vituperatoribus, his at natum vocent. Eu ius simul percipit expetendis, eum cu meliore probatus adipisci, semper suavitate cum ut. Ne wisi dicant vix. Eum vivendo accusata suscipiantur at. Vix euismod percipitur ut, summo nominavi similique vis ex.
</p>
</div>
```

Con height: auto, se adapta el div al contenido que contenga.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
.portfolio{
height: auto;
background:#f2f2f2;
padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar *algo* de texto que describa tu solución? Con el código así sin más no queda claro que estás recomendando usar `height: auto` no qué es lo que eso significa o qué implica para esa solución